# How to switch between windows 8 and Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-8

I have been using Windows 8 pro previously then I installed Ubuntu with the Windows installer.

The installation was successful but when I start my computer it doesn't ask me which OS to boot and it boots Ubuntu as default OS. I have things to do in both OS's so I need to switch between them. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

> 1 time

Hold down (right) SHIFT to display the menu during boot. In certain cases, pressing the ESC key may also display the menu.

> Permanent

You need to tell the bootloader to stop starting the default OS.

From command line:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

The option

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

will wait 10 seconds before starting the default OS. If you set it to `-1` it will wait for you to choose an OS. After editing configuration you need to do a

```
sudo update-grub
```

for it to accept the changes the next time you boot.